# Derivative of $u(t)(f(t,x))$ in Bochner spaces

Tags: derivatives, sobolev-spaces, bochner-spaces

Let $u \in C^\infty((0,T); H^1_0(\Omega))$ where $\Omega$ is bounded and smooth. Let $f\colon (0,T)\times \Omega \to \Omega$ be smooth with $f_t$ and $f$ uniformly bounded pointwise. Here $f_t$ refers to differentiation with respect to the first argument.

Is it true that
$$\frac{d}{dt} (u(t)(f(t,x))) = u_t(t)(f(t,x))+ \nabla u(t)(f(t,x)) \cdot f_t(t ,x)$$

The $\nabla u$ means the weak gradient btw.

How could one prove this?

Comment: $f$ shouldn't be a function that have values in $\Omega$?

Comment: @Youem You are right, sorry

Answer (score 0):

If $x$ is fixed let $b : (0,T)\times(0,T)\to \mathbb R$ defined by $$b(s, v) = u(s)(f(v, x))$$

It is clear that:

$$\frac{\partial b}{\partial s}(s, v) = u_t(s)(f(v,x))$$ and by the chain rule $$\frac{\partial b}{\partial v}(s, v) = \nabla u(s)(f(v,x)) \cdot f_t(v,x)$$
and $a(t) = u(t)(f(t,x)) = b(t, t)$ then by chain rule

\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt} a(t) &= \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt} b(t, t)\\
&= \frac{\partial b}{\partial s}(t, t)\frac{\partial s}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial b}{\partial v}(t, t)\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}\\
&= u_t(t)(f(t,x)) + \nabla u(t)(f(t,x))\cdot f_t(t,x)
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks, but, are You sure the chain rule is valid? $u(t)$ is only in $H^1_0$ (for fixed $t$)